# save_kable as pdf changes structure

Tags: r, dataframe, pdf, kable

I created a table using

```
df %>%  
    mutate_if(is.numeric,round,digits = 2) %>%
    kable(format="simple", caption="Statistical evaluation")  %>%
    save_kable(file="test.pdf")
```

Do you know how to fix this? Is there an alternative?

**EDIT:** This is the data

```
structure(list(TPR = c(0.934842767295597, 0.92922841571852), 
    FPR = c(0.516589250165893, 0.525067529460655), ACC = c(0.867615330138182, 
    0.866211826128489), FAR = c(0.0881670095698295, 0.0834131044726853
    ), CSI = c(0.85734568558549, 0.856776377557092), BS = c(1.02523463957426, 
    1.01379194951716), HSS = c(0.444709565304963, 0.419220178831526
    ), tr = c(0.22, 0.25)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

and this the pdf
[image]

Comment: Please make your question reproducible include the output of `dput(df)` in the question . The pdf image is not readable.

Comment: You cannot see the pdf at all?

Comment: Why to you want `format = "simple"` for a pdf? The pdf image in the question is not readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done entirely in `kableExtra`. For pdf output typically you do need `format = "latex"`. If you want to edit the appearance of the table `kableExtra` has plenty of options.

```r
df1 <- structure(list(TPR = c(0.934842767295597, 0.92922841571852), 
                      FPR = c(0.516589250165893, 0.525067529460655), ACC = c(0.867615330138182, 
                                                                             0.866211826128489), FAR = c(0.0881670095698295, 0.0834131044726853
                                                                             ), CSI = c(0.85734568558549, 0.856776377557092), BS = c(1.02523463957426, 
                                                                                                                                     1.01379194951716), HSS = c(0.444709565304963, 0.419220178831526
                                                                                                                                     ), tr = c(0.22, 0.25)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                     ), row.names = c(NA, -2L))


library(kableExtra)

df1 |> 
  kable(format = "latex",
        digits = 2,
        caption="Statistical evaluation")  |> 
  save_kable(file="test.pdf")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am getting a warning message´for save_kable: Warning message in system(paste0("xelatex -interaction=batchmode \"", temp_tex_file, : execution error which I need to solve. But nevertheless, your answer is helpful!